# How can I use Regex to abbreviate words that all start with a capital letter

Tags: python, regex, nsregularexpression

I want to abbreviate words from a string by writing a python script.
for example, I studied in King Saud University, which is in Riyadh, the capital of Saudi Arabia; becomes I studied in KSU, which is in Riyadh, the capital of SA.

I tried to use the lambda, to scan all the string but I couldn't remove the rest of the word after finding it.

```
import re
str = "I studied in King Saud University, which is in Riyadh, the capital of Saudi Arabia"

result = re.sub(r"\b[A-Z]", lambda x: x.group()  ,str)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually consume two or more words starting with an uppercase letter.

You can use something like

```py
result = re.sub(r"\b[A-Z]\w*(?:\s+[A-Z]\w*)+", lambda x: "".join(c[0] for c in x.group().split()), text)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/mqyFZz):

```py
import re
text = "I studied in King Saud University, which is in Riyadh, the capital of Saudi Arabia"
result = re.sub(r"\b[A-Z]\w*(?:\s+[A-Z]\w*)+", lambda x: "".join(c[0] for c in x.group().split()), text)
print(result)
# => I studied in KSU, which is in Riyadh, the capital of SA
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vBTfY1/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
- `\w*` - zero or more word chars
- `(?:\s+[A-Z]\w*)+` - one or more occurrences of

  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `[A-Z]\w*` - an uppercase ASCII letter and then zero or more word chars.

The `"".join(c[0] for c in x.group().split())` part grabs first chars from the non-whitespace chunks in the match value and joins them into a single string.

To support all Unicode uppercase letters, I'd advise to use PyPi regex module, and use

```py
import regex
#...
result = regex.sub(r"\b\p{Lu}\p{L}*(?:\s+\p{Lu}\p{L}*)+", lambda x: "".join(c[0] for c in x.group().split()), text)
```

where `\p{Lu}` matches any Unicode uppercase letter and `\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works. I removed the lambda function and replaced every appearance of capital letters K,S,U each followed by lowercase letters and a space.

```
import re
str = "I studied in King Saud University, which is in Riyadh, the capital of Saudi Arabia"
find = re.compile(r"[K][a-z]+\s[S][a-z]+\s[U][a-z]+")
substitute = "KSU"

print(find.sub(substitute,str))
```

Comment: I think OP is looking for a generic regex instead of one that will only work on the example string