# How can I use Regex to extract all words that written in the camel case

Tags: python, regex

I tried to extract all consecutive capitalized words in a given string written with no spacing in between.

E.g. `The University Of Sydney` => `TheUniversityOfSydney`, `Regular Expression` => `RegularExpression`, and `This Is A Simple Variable` => `ThisIsASimpleVariable`.

I start with this code, but it comes as a list:

```py
import re
string = "I write a syntax of Regular Expression"
result = re.findall(r"\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b", string)
print(result)
```

I expect to get `RegularExpression` here.

Comment: What kind of output were you expecting?

Comment: RegularExpression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```py
import re
text = "I write a syntax of Regular Expression"
rx = r"\b[A-Z]\w*(?:\s+[A-Z]\w*)+"
result = ["".join(x.split()) for x in re.findall(rx, text)]
print(result) # => ['RegularExpression']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/XeJyGf).

The regex is explained in [How can I use Regex to abbreviate words that all start with a capital letter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71373816/3832970).

In this case, the regex is used in `re.findall` to extract matches, and `"".join(x.split())` is a post-process step to remove all whitespaces from the found texts.

If you only expect one single match in each string, use `re.search`:

```py
import re
text = "I write a syntax of Regular Expression"
rx = r"\b[A-Z]\w*(?:\s+[A-Z]\w*)+"
result = re.search(rx, text)
if result:
    print( "".join(result.group().split()) ) # => 'RegularExpression'
```